# differences between conditional probability and dependency

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, copula, dependent-variable

Sometimes, I read articles about conditional probabilities and other articles about conditional dependency. My question what is the main differences between them?

For example, 
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)".

So, a copula is a measure of the dependency structures in the probability theory. Hence, the probability and dependency are different.

Answer (score 1):

A simple search would have revelaed the answer, which is already clear from the names.

1. Conditional probability is a measure of the probability of an event given that another event has occurred.
2. Conditional dependence is a relationship between two or more events that are dependent when a third event occurs.

Comment: @thank you for your answer. Copula, for example, is a measuring method for the dependency structures. However, the mathematical expression of the copula is the probability of an event given another event.